# Выделить из строки текст после ":" и записать в текстовый файл

Tags: python, база-данных

Есть текстовый файл, где записаны данные пользователей. Мне нужно отделить пароль от почты: - пароль записан после двоеточия (:); необходимо, чтобы программа брала из текстового документа по одной строке, и то, что после ":" записывала в новый текстовый файл. Я пытался это сделать но мой код сохраняет в текстовый файл только 1 последний пароль. Пожалуйста, помогите.

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
a = open("mybase.txt")
for Line in a:
    file_1 = open("sorted.txt", "w")
    file_1.write(Line[Line.find(':')+1:])
    file_1.close()
```

Если после оператора `for` не писать те 3 строки? а написать

```
print(Line[Line.find(':')+1:])
```

будут выведены все пароли после ":". Как сделать, чтобы их в текстовый документ записало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открывайте файл на запись до цикла. И лучше делайте это с помощью `with`, тогда не нужно будет закрывать файл, он сам закроется при выходе управления из блока кода:

```py
import time

time.sleep(5)
with open("mybase.txt") as a:
    with open("sorted.txt", "w") as file_1:
        for Line in a:
            file_1.write(Line[Line.find(':')+1:])
```

Сейчас вы на каждой итерации цикла открываете файл и целиком перезаписываете его. Поэтому в файле остаётся только результат работы последней итерации цикла.